# Windows on-screen keyboard and java.awt.Robot mouse problems

Tags: java, windows, touch

I'm using `java.awt.Robot` to send mouse events on a Windows 7 (64-bit) system. This is basically to convert touch events to mouse input. For allowing users to enter characters in applications I was planning on reusing the built-in Windows on-screen keyboard (osk.exe).

However, I've hit a snag. Any mouse down event generated by `Robot` that happens when the cursor is over the window decoration of the OSK window (title bar, system menu, etc) freezes the mouse. It seems only the mouse down event is processed, as I can see OSK get focus. The `Robot` does keep sending other mouse events but they have no effect on the OSK window. The only way out is to press/release the physical USB mouse attached to the system.

The strange thing is that using OSK for entering characters by sending mouse presses on the OSK keyboard buttons from `Robot` is working fine. It's just that trying to move (or close) the OSK window freezes the mouse handling.

I've seen a few other questions about OSK and events, indicating that OSK is a bit of a special application. But I'm wondering what the difference is between the mouse events generated by `Robot` and the ones from the USB mouse, as OSK reacts differently to them and `Robot` supposedly generates native events?

Comment: you are releasing the mouse robot right?
Robot#mouseRelease(int button);

Comment: Sure, for example, when sending down, a series of moves and a release event in sequence, e.g. over the OSK title bar, the down event happens but no window move occurs. The mouse is also not released.

Comment: 'Sure'? 
  Robot robot = new Robot();
  robot.mousePress(1);
  robot.delay(10);
  robot.mouseRelease(1);

Comment: To be more clear: the mouse interaction works. I can move, resize, open/close, etc all windows, except the OSK one.